# Could not find a ready tiller pod (Error)

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm

I set up helm and tiller. I have tiller-deploy . 
yesterday , i could regularly run. But today  I get this error message

```
Error: could not find a ready tiller pod
```

How can i fix it. Some info which i tried by command.

It can't get server infomation .

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.1", 
GitCommit:"5270352a09c7e8b6e8c9593002a73535276507c0", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find a ready tiller pod
```

I have a running tiller-deploy-675656bbcf-5q5gp.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                   READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
tiller-deploy-675656bbcf-5q5gp         1/1     Running   0          46h
tunnelfront-557bbd9fb5-b8g7h           1/1     Running   0          47h
```

Check the deployed thing.

```
$ kubectl get deploy -n kube-system
NAME                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
tiller-deploy          0/1     1            0           46h
tunnelfront            0/1     1            0           47h
```

Describe the tiller-deploy infomation, but it is not ready.

```
$ kubectl describe pod tiller-deploy -n kube-system
Name:               tiller-deploy-675656bbcf-5q5gp
Namespace:          kube-system
Priority:           0
PriorityClassName:  <none>
Node:               aks-default-41105859-0/10.240.0.4
Start Time:         Wed, 19 Jun 2019 20:09:25 +0700
Labels:             app=helm
                    name=tiller
                    pod-template-hash=675656bbcf
Annotations:        <none>
Status:             Running
IP:                 10.244.1.3
Controlled By:      ReplicaSet/tiller-deploy-675656bbcf
Containers:
  tiller:
    Container ID:   docker://7e9b73333473bc5026b4790031173adf9e77669ff4eb856840766052395dba85
    Image:          gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.14.1
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller@sha256:f8002b91997fdc2c15a9c2aa994bea117b5b1683933f3144369862f0883c3c42
    Ports:          44134/TCP, 44135/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 19 Jun 2019 20:09:35 +0700
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:44135/liveness delay=1s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:44135/readiness delay=1s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      TILLER_NAMESPACE:    kube-system
      TILLER_HISTORY_MAX:  0
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-5b6d7 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-5b6d7:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-5b6d7
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

That all.

Comment: Help me please!

Comment: Maybe there is something update for the AKS server. Try to restart the nodes and then try again.

Comment: i have deleted the Kubernetes service,and redeploy the project . and it worked .Next time i will try to restart the nodes, thanks you.

Comment: It's the final way and you cannot just delete the cluster while there are a lot of things deployed in it.

Comment: yes, but how can i restart the node ? i find but it sound no way

Comment: Just find the group and restart the node.

Comment: Thanks you . I will try to restart the node when it occur

Comment: If you are not familiar with K8s definition, then I suggest you go with Rancher. A little more UI maybe give you more comfortable and easier to control things

Answer (score 12):

In my case

```
helm init --upgrade
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue. Everything was working fine but i was stuck with the same error.
Following commands saved me

```
$ kubectl delete deployment tiller-deploy --namespace kube-system
$ helm init
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue. In my case, i was revoked RBAC and added back. When I first initiated helm, I had created the service accounts. I was then revoked access to the cluster and added back. Not exactly sure if this was the cause but when trying to do helm ls i get that error.

I tried the helm init --upgrade as suggested by Alexey but was not successful.

I restarted the tiller pod and everything worked again. *Shrugs*